# How to highlight text in a sentence using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, openxml, wordprocessingml

I am using below code to search and highlight text in a MS Word document, it works fine for point 1 but not point 2:

```
1. John Alter
```

I search for `Alter` or `John`, it highlights `John`/`Alter` - works.

```
2. I am going to school
```

I search for `going`, it highlights `going` but it changes its order as `I am to school going` - does not work.

How to fix point 2? Below is my code.

```
private void HighLightText(Paragraph paragraph, string text)
{
    string textOfRun = string.Empty;
    var runCollection = paragraph.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run>();
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run runAfter = null;

    //find the run part which contains the characters
    foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run run in runCollection)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(paragraph.InnerText) &&  paragraph.InnerText != "\\s")
            textOfRun = run.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>().Text;                                  

         if (textOfRun.IndexOf(text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
         {    
             //remove the character from this run part
             run.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>().Text = Regex.Replace(textOfRun, text, string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);//textOfRun.Replace(text, string.Empty);
             runAfter = run;
             break;    
         }    
     }

     //create a new run with your customization font and the character as its text
     DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run HighLightRun = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run();
     DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.RunProperties runPro = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.RunProperties();
     Highlight highlight = new Highlight() { Val = HighlightColorValues.Yellow };
     DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text runText = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text() { Text = text };

     runPro.Append(highlight);
     HighLightRun.Append(runPro);
     HighLightRun.Append(runText);

     //insert the new created run part
     paragraph.InsertAfter(HighLightRun, runAfter);    
}
```

Comment: @pfx: Can you check this ?

Comment: can you please add the document and also any other code that allows users to easily reproduce your problem?

Comment: I have already added code with my post and if you need document just add my point 2 to the code - Add, I am going to school to the document and use my above code it will highlight search word but it will make it like - I am school to going , here going is the word to be highlighted

Comment: `paragraph.InsertAfter` seems a likely culprit.  Not that helpful of a comment, I know :)  According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.paragraph_members.aspx there is also an InsertAt method that may be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split-up your `Run` if you want to highlight some text in the middle of that `Run`. So replacing the search text with an empty string won't work.

Your original text structure looks like:

```
<Run>
    <Text>
        I am going to school
    </Text>
</Run>
```

If you want to highlight the `going` word, you need to make a more complex structure out of it:

```
<Run>
    <Text>
        I am 
    </Text>
</Run>
<Run>
    <Text>
        going
    </Text>
</Run>
<Run>
    <Text>
         to school
    </Text>
</Run>
```

Then, the `Run` in the middle can be set-up for highlighting.

Here is a working code sample. Please note, **there's no error handing in this code**! It should give you some idea how to solve your task. Implement the proper exception handing for production usage!

Also note that this sample only searches for the first occurrence, as it is in your code. If you need to highlight multiple search matches, you will have to improve this code.

```
void HighLightText(Paragraph paragraph, string text)
{
    // Search for a first occurrence of the text in the text runs
    var found = paragraph
        .Descendants<Run>()
        .Where(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.InnerText) && r.InnerText != "\\s")
        .Select(r =>
        {
            var runText = r.GetFirstChild<Text>();
            int index = runText.Text.IndexOf(text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            // 'Run' is a reference to the text run we found,
            // TextNode is a reference to the run's Text object,
            // 'TokenIndex` is the index of the search string in run's text
            return new { Run = r, TextNode = runText, TokenIndex = index };
        })                    
        .FirstOrDefault(o => o.TokenIndex >= 0);

    // Nothing found -- escape
    if (found == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Create a node for highlighted text as a clone (to preserve formatting etc)
    var highlightRun = found.Run.CloneNode(true);

    // Add the highlight node after the found text run and set up the highlighting
    paragraph.InsertAfter(highlightRun, found.Run);
    highlightRun.GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = text;
    RunProperties runPro = new RunProperties();
    Highlight highlight = new Highlight { Val = HighlightColorValues.Yellow };

    runPro.AppendChild(highlight);
    highlightRun.InsertAt(runPro, 0); 

    // Check if there's some text in the text run *after* the found text
    int remainderLength = found.TextNode.Text.Length - found.TokenIndex - text.Length;
    if (remainderLength > 0)
    {
        // There is some text after the highlighted section --
        // insert it in a separate text run after the highlighted text run
        var remainderRun = found.Run.CloneNode(true);
        paragraph.InsertAfter(remainderRun, highlightRun);  
        var textNode = remainderRun.GetFirstChild<Text>();
        textNode.Text = found.TextNode.Text.Substring(found.TokenIndex + text.Length);

        // We need to set up this to preserve the spaces between text runs
        textNode.Space = new EnumValue<SpaceProcessingModeValues>(SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve);
    }

    // Check if there's some text *before* the found text
    if (found.TokenIndex > 0)
    {
        // Something is left before the highlighted text,
        // so make the original text run contain only that portion
        found.TextNode.Text = found.TextNode.Text.Remove(found.TokenIndex);

        // We need to set up this to preserve the spaces between text runs
        found.TextNode.Space = new EnumValue<SpaceProcessingModeValues>(SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve);  
    }
    else
    {
        // There's nothing before the highlighted text -- remove the unneeded text run
        paragraph.RemoveChild(found.Run);
    }
}
```

This code works for highlighting the `I`, `going`, or `school` words in the `I am going to school` sentence.

Comment: Thanks,Your code is working with some changes. However same approach does not work for presentation(.pptx) documents..I have updated the code above for same..it corrupts the file and ask to repair while opening pptx and after opening it highlights the word but it does not preserves the formatting..can you help on same ?

Comment: @user662285 changing the scope of a question like that (moving the goal post) is never cool. Especially as the provided answer would have been originally crafted based on the original request targeting word documents.

Comment: my above question does not mean i will not give bounty points, irrespective of whether it is answered for pptx or not, i am just curious to understand why it does not work for pptx as both uses run and text...My intention is not to change the scope of the question

Comment: @user662285 noted and understood.

Comment: @dymanoid : Let me know if you want me to open new question for pptx , i thought if it can be answered here, if not i will open new question for same ? Let me know

Comment: This code only works for `Wordprocessing.Paragraph`. I am pretty sure it will not work for `OpenXmlDrawing.Paragraph`. For PowerPoint, you should ask another question because the XML structure of the PowerPoint documents is different.

Comment: Thanks , i will do the same.

Comment: @dymanoid : Structure is same for pptx as well i debugged the code and found problerm is  highlightRun.InsertAt(runPro,0);  it corrupts the file but i am not able to figure out why it is happening like this ? Can you suggest something ?

Comment: I think you should add this information to the related question, not to this one. The reason why this corrupts the document is that the XML structure of the PowerPoint document is different. You cannot just use this code "as is" for other document types.